# Acl file configuration in Mosquitto

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have acl file in my mosquito:

```
user b
topic read s1#
topic write s1#

topic write s2
topic read s2


pattern write s3_%c#
pattern read s3_%c#

pattern write s4_%c
pattern read s4_%c


pattern  write s5_%u#
pattern  read s5_%u#

pattern  write s6_%u
pattern  read s6_%u
```

Request below to topic `s4_abc` from client id `abc` works fine:

```
mosquitto_pub -h servername -t s4_abc -m "test" -p 1883 -u b -P b -i abc -d
```

Request below to topic `s3_abcA` from client id `abc` fails:

```
mosquitto_pub -h servername -t s3_abcA -m "test" -p 1883 -u b -P b -i abc -d
```

Why it fails? I'm expecting that pattern s3_%c# means any phrase in topic after "s3_abc" is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You topics & patterns in the ACL file are not valid, they need to have a `/` between the wildcard characters.

Wildcards only match whole topic segments.

The same is also true for the `%u` and `%c`

From the mosquitto.conf man page:

> The patterns available for substition are:
>
> %c to match the client id of the client %u to match the username of
>   the client. **The substitution pattern must be the only text for that
>   level of hierarchy**. Pattern ACLs apply to all users even if the "user"
>   keyword has previously been given.
>
> Example:
>
> pattern write sensor/%u/data
>
> Allow access for bridge connection messages:
>
> pattern write $SYS/broker/connection/%c/state